# Simple bat file log to text but error

Tags: windows, command-line, batch-file

I created 2 simple bat files, and I keep on getting the same error on both. I wanted to log what is on the bat file into a text document. The error is : `The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process.`  Is it because I am Called the bat file within itself?

**Code 1**

```
@echo off

:BEGIN
net stop redmineMongrel1
TIMEOUT /T 15
net start redmineMongrel1
goto SUCCESS

:SUCCESS
"C:\Documents and Settings\Administrator\My Documents\MongrelRestartScript.bat" > "C:\Documents and Settings\Administrator\My Documents\MongrelRestart.log"
ECHO Mongrel Restart Successful  %DATE%>> "C:\Documents and Settings\Administrator\My Documents\MongrelRestart.log"
goto END

:FAIL
ECHO.>"C:\Documents and Settings\Administrator\My Documents\MongrelRestart.log"
ECHO Mongrel Restart FAILED %DATE%>> "C:\Documents and Settings\Administrator\My Documents\MongrelRestart.log"

:END
echo END OF BAT FILE
```

**Code 2**

```
@echo off


:BEGIN
DEL "D:\BACKUPS\RedmineFolder" /s /q 
RD "D:\BACKUPS\RedmineFolder" /s /q


xcopy C:\BitNami\apps\redmine "D:\BACKUPS\RedmineFolder" /e /h /r /y /I
goto SUCCESS

:SUCCESS
ECHO.>"C:\Documents and Settings\Administrator\My Documents\RedmineBackupLog.log"
ECHO Redmine Backup Successful  %DATE%>> "C:\Documents and Settings\Administrator\My Documents\RedmineBackupLog.log"
"C:\Documents and Settings\Administrator\My Documents\RedmineBackUpScript.bat" >> "C:\Documents and Settings\Administrator\My Documents\RedmineBackupLog.log"
goto END

:FAIL
ECHO.>"C:\Documents and Settings\Administrator\My Documents\RedmineBackupLog.log"
ECHO Redmine Backup  FAILED %DATE%>> "C:\Documents and Settings\Administrator\My Documents\RedmineBackupLog.log"

:END
echo END OF BAT FILE
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe it is the case. I've added another bat file to call this one like so :

**MAIN.bat**

`"C:\Documents and Settings\Administrator\My Documents\DoThis.bat" > "C:\Documents and Settings\Administrator\My Documents\LogEverything.log" 2>&1`

The 2>&1 is logging every text (from bat file and command line), which is quite useful.

Answer (score 1):

This problem is not because you are calling the bat file from within itself.  It is perfectly acceptable to do this in dos.

If you are trying to dump the contents of the bat file, use 'type' :

```
type filename > logfile
```

It is likely that your .log file is opened by another process.
You can use filemon for windows to see what processes might be accessing the file: [filemon](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896642.aspx)